# Deserializing JSON with different types for serialization/deserialization

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a class:

```
[DataContract]
public class A
{
    [DataMember]
    public B ArbitraryProperty { get; set;}
}
```

When serialized, "ArbitraryProperty" needs to be in the form of class "B":

```
[DataContract]
public class B
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ValueA { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ValueB { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the JSON output:

```
{
    "ArbitraryProperty": { "ValueA": "I'm a value.", "ValueB": "I'm a value too!" }
}
```

When I get that same object back from the server though, the property comes back as a simple string like this:

```
{
    "ArbitraryProperty": "I'm not a B, muahahaha!!!"
}
```

There has to be a trick to letting the DataContractJsonSerializer know that it should deserialize the value to a string instead of a "B".

Is there a special way to set up class "A"? :/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have two classes, one that has a `B` property, and one that has a `string` property. Your output and what you say comes back are two totally unrelated data structures.

Comment: @JoeEnos Hence the problem :) I really don't want to have to make different classes for my request and response types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the right way to go - I think the right answer for readability and usability is to properly type a request and a response class. But...Only thing I can think of is to make the property an `object` rather than strongly typing it. You'll just need to ensure that when you assign a value to it, you assign the right type.

```
public class A
{
    public object ArbitraryProperty { get; set; }
}
```

It will still serialize properly:

```
var a = new A { ArbitraryProperty = new B { ValueA = "a", ValueB = "b" } };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

When the object comes back, deserializing will put that string into the property.

```
json = "{'ArbitraryProperty':'This is some string'}";
a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```

This code works with simple serialize/deserialize from JSON.NET, but I don't know if WebAPI or whatever technology you're using will like it.

Comment: I figured it was going to look something like that. I think I'll take your advice, do the right thing, and just create the different types. Thanks!